# Traveling to Sri Lanka with Finland Refugee Travel Document

Tags: visas, international-travel, paperwork, refugees, sri-lanka

My girlfriend is from Myanmar. She has been granted refugee status in Finland and has a refugee travel document (RTD) issued by Finland. We are planning to visit Sri Lanka this year.

Is it possible to enter Sri Lanka using this RTD? Or should we cancel this trip?

Comment: _Is it possible to enter Sri Lanka using this RTD?_ Presumably, but the question is if you can apply for an ETA online or on arrival at the airport, or if you must obtain a visa in advance. The Sri Lankan [online ETA application site](https://eta.gov.lk/slvisa/visainfo/center.jsp?locale=en_US) is extremely unclear on if and how this is possible. I would recommend to try getting in touch with the [department of immigration](https://eta.gov.lk/slvisa/visainfo/contact.jsp) and/or the [embassy in Stockholm](https://www.stockholm.embassy.gov.lk/en/) for further advice.